# Why do I get an empty picture in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a mini gallery in Angular JS.
So, there is an array of SRC images: `$scope.link.images` and function:

```
$scope.toogleImage = function (){
                if($scope.link.images.length > $scope.index){
                    ++$scope.index;
                } else {
                    $scope.index = 0;
                }
                $scope.mainImage = $scope.link.images[$scope.index];
            }
```

In array there are six elements.
When I call the method `$scope.toogleImage` it increments `$scope.index` and takes element from the array. So, when `$scope.index = 6` I get an empty `SRC` from array. Why?

Comment: There does not seem to a range check for array's length,you are incrementing past the end

Comment: If your array has six elements, there's no element at index=6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only six elements, then in a zero-based array array[6] is nothing, since the valid values are only 0,1,2,3,4,5.

You can rewrite your function the following way:

```
$scope.toogleImage = function (){
     $scope.mainImage = $scope.link.images[++$scope.index % $scope.link.images.length];
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific as to what doesn't work. The index changes correctly, maybe you have a different issue.

Comment: What is operator `%`? My slider does not work, so images are not changed

Comment: It's the [Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) operator. Take a look in the "Remainder" section.